# How to get entry text in glade3 in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, gtk3, glade

Its first my first time in stackoverflow to get help.
Im making a Ruby GUI with glade3, but i dont really now how to get texts from an entry box?
It should read the text from entry box and write it in an excel sheet.

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: Have you tried to access values of UI controls in glade? See related QA : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263216/glade3-and-c-programming?rq=1

Comment: I have seen this QA, its written i C but i need it in Ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See example here: https://xrob.wordpress.com/2007/04/20/creating-a-gui-application-using-glade-and-ruby/

> We want to change something in the application so we will need to assign a variable to the widget that we want to alter. We want to alter “label1” and so we insert this code in the button1_clicked function.

```
@myEntryBox = @glade.get_widget(“myEntryBox”)
# You can now access properties like '@myEntryBox.text'
# Refer to documentation for exact name of the attribute
```